# Perl '->' strange notation

Tags: perl, syntax

what is this '->' thingy doing in the below context I have no clue what it means.
This is not an object we create at least not the traditional way with new nor I can imagine the '->' lines are arguments to a subroutine call.

```
my $Interface = SOAP::Lite
  -> uri("urn:iControl:$name")
  -> readable(1)
  -> proxy("https://$sHost/iControl/iControlPortal.cgi");
```

A hint is appreciated to move on with this first time seen syntax after several years using Perl every now and then.

I am confused.

thx/Hermann

Comment: It is same as `SOAP::Lite->uri("urn:iControl:$name")->(..)` and as it seems every method call returns object himself.

Comment: so we call several methods of the Lite module in a chain, correct ?

Comment: This is documented in perlref. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

Comment: `->` is used when you're using a reference and wants to access its contents or calling a method (I think it's same syntax than C++ with object pointers).

Comment: In Perl, `new` is not a special name.  Object constructors can be named anything at all (although `new` is common).  In this case, the constructor method of SOAP::Lite is `uri`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
a
   ->b(...)
   ->c(...)
   ->d(...)
```

is just a more readable way to write

```
a->b(...)->c(...)->d(...)
```

And it means

```
( ( a->b(...) )->c(...) )->d(...)
```

or

```
my $temp1 = a->b(...);
my $temp2 = $temp1->c(...);
$temp2->d(...)
```

It's just a chain of methods calls, where one method returns an object that serves as the invocant for the next.

SOAP::Lite uses a common "trick" of having setters returning the object whose attribute is set, allowing

```
 my $obj = Class->new();
 $obj->setter1(...);
 $obj->setter2(...);
 $obj->setter3(...);
```

to be written as

```
 my $obj = Class->new()
    ->setter1(...)
    ->setter2(...)
    ->setter3(...);
```